# Highcharts Image in Tooltip

Tags: highcharts

If we set useHTML: true for the tooltip and include an image, the image displays fine, but all the series data falls outside of the tooltip.
Are we doing something wrong?

```
 tooltip: {
             useHTML: true,
             headerFormat: '<img src="/images/sample.jpg" width="150"/><br />► Listing {point.x}<br />',
             pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">► {series.name} : </span> {point.y:, .0f} <br />', 
             split: false,
             shared: true
          },
```

Answer (score -1):

I tried to reproduce the issue which you have described, but it seems that everything works fine.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/hw6kt2cv/

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  tooltip: {
    useHTML: true,
    headerFormat: '<img src="https://img.webmd.com/dtmcms/live/webmd/consumer_assets/site_images/article_thumbnails/other/dog_cool_summer_slideshow/1800x1200_dog_cool_summer_other.jpg" width="150"/><br />► Listing {point.x}<br />',
    pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">► {series.name} : </span> {point.y:, .0f} <br />',
    split: false,
    shared: true
  },
  series: [{
    data: [43934, 52503, 57177, 69658, 97031, 119931, 137133, 154175]
  }]
});
```

Maybe some other options have an impact on your chart? Could you share a sample which will show the issue?

---

According to the comments - using the `tooltip.outside` should fix the described issue.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/1xshj85w/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.outside

Comment: Hi, your own sample shows the same problem! Just hover on the first point and you will see the issue. When you move off the first point then it becomes ok.